# Incrementing a variable name

Tags: javascript

Is there a possibility to iterate over a variable named `nextcanvas(number)`?

```
function move_to_nextcanvas ()
{
    var destCtx = nextcanvas1.getContext('2d');
    destCtx.drawImage(maincanvas, 0, 0, 600, 300, 0, 0, 300, 150);
}
```

So every time I click a button, it will count up `nextcanvas1` to `nextcanvas2`, then `nextcanvas3`, etc. up to `nextcanvas8`.

I have a main canvas in which I am drawing something, and every time I click the "send" button, the actual drawing of the main canvas should be sent to the next of the 8 canvasses.

This method works for me, but only for the first canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do something like this:

```
var canvases = [canvasobj1,canvasobj2,etc],
    canvasIdx = 0;

function moveToNextCanvas() { 
    var destCtx = canvases[canvasIdx].getContext('2d');
    destCtx.drawImage(mainCanvas, 0, 0, 600, 300, 0, 0, 300, 150);
    canvasIdx++;
    if (canvasIdx > canvases.length) canvasIdx = 0;
}
```

Basically you use a pointer.  The benefit of this is that you can order the canvases in any way you wish - you could easily populate the array by enumerating the page or some other method.